# I need to review 2 seminal CompSci papers in a chosen topic, suggestions please

Tags: web-services, comet, web-standards

I come from a multimedia background as opposed to a pure-CS background so I would find a heavy CS-paper about subjects like algorithms hard to review.

I'm interested mainly in web technologies, particularly areas like web standards, push technologies (comet, web hooks etc..), social graphing, online data portability. Other topic suggestions are welcome too.

The problem is that any papers that I can find on these topics couldn't really be called seminal because they are quite recent and consequently haven't been cited by very many other papers.

I'd love to hear suggestions about research topics or recommended papers in a chosen topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late, but you never know...

Trust metrics are a topic that is fairly abstract and algorithmic, but with important applications to important trends in web services, particularly recommender networks.  I wrote [a brief annotated bibliography](http://www.advogato.org/person/chalst/diary/189.html) on some research on trust metrics that are relevant to Raph Levien's idea of attack-resistant trust metrics.

The original Google papers, [The PageRank citation ranking: Bringing order to the Web. http://dbpubs.stanford.edu:8090/pub/showDoc.Fulltext?lang=en&doc=1999-66&format=pdf&compression=.](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/422/1/1999-66.pdf) and [The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/361/) are excellent for discussion.  Levien has explained how PageRank can be seen as an attack-resistant trust metric.

Answer (score 1):

I think the seminal paper for the hypertext concept is [As We May Think](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_We_May_Think), by Vannevar Bush.

Another highly influential...system? paper? is the [Xanadu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Xanadu) approach.

Of course, the Web's seminal paper is [Tim Berners-Lee](http://www.w3.org/Proposal.html)'s initial proposal.

I think there's a vast...unacademicalness (made that word up) here. Who wrote the academic paper for Facebook or other social media? What about Mosaic?  Livejournal is rumored to have been written in bits and pieces for student projects initially. Maybe there *are* papers that got written for them - I don't know. Doesn't seem like it tho'.

Comment: Some years back, I noticed how hard it was to find anything at all written on the subject of search quality.  My guess then was that anyone who had anything interesting to say on the subject was immediately hired by Google or a competitor and shut up with an NDA.  A similar effect might be occuring here

Comment: @Charles: Possibly. My suspicion is that a lot of people say, "hey, let's do XYZ", and do it; since it's not theory-driven, there's no academic papers written. E.g., Stack Overflow.

Comment: the thing is, a lot of it is *so* nice from a mathematical perspective: it's all interesting applications of graph theory.  And there's quite a long list of researchers who work I used to follow who are now behind the Google curtain, e.g., Raph Levien.

Answer (score 0):

None of your areas of interest is really "foundational", which is probably why you have received so few responses.  But here are a couple of ideas of topics on which you should be able to find seminal papers with some help from a reference librarian, and they have some connection to networks and computing:

- Dijkstra's seminal algorithm for finding shortest paths.
- Minimum spanning tree—I'd have a look at Bernard Chazelle's paper on doing MST in inverse-Ackermann time; he'll have some older references.

One suggestion that may be further from your interests, but one I've actually read and is a stunningly good paper:

- Don Knuth's original paper on LR parsing.